# does port 8080 need port_forwarding?

Tags: udp, port-forwarding

is port 8080 open (auto forwarded) in all devices? i used it without PortForwarding and UDP packets transferred successfully!
i expected the NAT to block this but public ip address worked simply!

i tested UDP on 4 different devices , 3 different internet connections and 2 other ports(8081,8082); it worked!

all internet conections that i used were mobile data.

Comment: NAT follows the rules you configure. What default rules are used may differ per device. Your question 'in all devices' makes this a very generic question which could be easily be answered with  a clear 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

> is port 8080 open (auto forwarded) in all devices?

Neither. A port is only open/listening when there's a service running on the port. It's only forwarded (between public and private network) when the NAT router is set up that way. Without NAT or filtering on the network the default should forward it though.

If your NAT router forwards public-to-private without explicit configuration (either destination NAT or 'exposed host') it must be regarded as a severe security issue. You either need a better router or an additional firewall.